# Administer android phone from my ubuntu desktop?

Tags: bluetooth, android

Is there some program to help me administer my android phone from my ubuntu desktop (which is always most recent, with updates). By administer I mean transfering files easily both ways (using bluetooth or otherwise), cleaning up the filesystem on the phone and possibly other simple tasks.

(My fingers are too large to do such comfortably on the phone).

**Edits**:

My phone is Samsung Galaxy J2 Core.
Android version is 8.1.0
Earlier, on a Debian system, I did this tasks via Nautilus and an usb cable. That does not work for me now!

Comment: Why is the file manager insufficient for these tasks?

Comment: Which file manager? How to prepare it for use with android? On debian earlier, I did it that way, with the usb cable, but I have not got that to work now on ubuntu ...

Comment: **any** file manager...  Have you simply tried plugging in the phone? You've told us nothing about the phone, not even what version of Android you are using, but you should be able to simply plug in the phone to your computer and navigate the file system as long as the phone is connected for file transfer.

Comment: @Nmath: See updates.

Comment: You will need to research how to use Android 8.1 to connect it to a computer. We can't help with showing you how to use your device. As long as the phone is set up for file transfer, it will show up in your file manager.  Otherwise, if you are having a specific problem on the Ubuntu side, you need to provide details and context about that particular problem and ask about that problem. The question, the way you asked it, has a simple answer: plug in the phone and use the file manager

Answer (score 2):

There is not much you can do with an (unrooted) android from the outside, except moving/cleaning files. This could be done with your "Files" filemanger (former Nautilus) by opening it and selecting the device on left hand side.
If you want go go into more details, you have to install "adb", a command line tool, that will you offer some adminstrative scripts.

See [more infos](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/#adbsetuplinux) on how to setup and work with adb

Samsung proclaims:

> USB Drivers may not seems like a big deal, in the beginning, if you
> connecting your Galaxy J2 Core with your computer. If you are using a
> Mac-based computer or a computer running Linux, then you may not face
> as many problems when you are connecting your Galaxy J2 Core.

If the device is still not recognized, you'll have to extend your udev-rules.
Find out the "vendor id" and create the follwing entry in

`/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

add:

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="????",MODE="0660",OWNER="your user name`"

where ???? should be shown in `dmesg`when plugged in and ,of course, your username...